# c# win32 SendMessage Command not working in VS Any CPU mode olnly in x86 mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sendmessage

I am working with an SDK but cannot get a SendMessage command working correctly on a 64bit OS. I have read http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendMessage and understand that IntPtr must be used but I still cannot get code to work. Here is parts of the original code.

```
public const Int32 WM_COPYDATA = 0x4A;          // Value of WM_COPYDATA

[DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
    public static extern Int32 SendMessage(
                                        IntPtr hWnd,
                                        UInt32 Msg,
                                        UInt32 wParam,
                                        ref COPYDATASTRUCT lParam);

 result = SendMessage(hWnd, ImageConnectionsMain.WM_COPYDATA, (Int32)0, ref cds);    // Win32API
```

I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Have you checked this http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures.COPYDATASTRUCT

Comment: What is "not working"? Read [ask].

Comment: In VS set to Any CPU mode there are no debugging errors but the message does not get sent. In X86 mode the message is sent and the receiving application responds.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the code working with a mixture of the link I put in the question and Ivan Storv's Link. I had missed replacing some Int32 with IntPtr. Many Thanks